# How to read document for Named Entity Recognition in OpenNLP

Tags: java, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am new to java and the requirement for me is to read a document and perform named entity documentation. For simple strings I did the following

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("data/en-ner-person.bin");
TokenNameFinderModel model = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
is.close();
NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(model);
String []sentence = new String[]{"Smith",
                "Smithosian",
                "is",
                "a",
                "person"
                };



   Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find(sentence);
```

However, I need to actually read the stream from a document and then generate an XML.
Can anyone please tell me how to do that

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Noone ever answered this so I hope it's not too late.

For the entity extraction, you need to have the document text in String format. Check stackoverflow for the many ways to get a doc text to String (short answer here is either use a BufferedInputStream for text files, or Apache Tika for MS and PDF files)

once you have the doc text in memory, this code should serve you to do the Sentence boundary detection, tokenization, and NER. Then take the result of this and generate an xmlDoc any way you want using the docname/docid, probably some file metadata, and the actual entity string, and type, and Span (the location of the NE hit in text)

this class should get you started

```
package processors;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetector;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerME;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.Span;

public class OpenNLPNER implements Runnable
{

    static TokenizerModel tm = null;
    static TokenNameFinderModel locModel = null;
    String doc;
    NameFinderME myNameFinder;
    TokenizerME wordBreaker;
    SentenceDetector sd;

    public OpenNLPNER()
    {
    }

    public OpenNLPNER(String document, SentenceDetector sd, NameFinderME mf, TokenizerME wordBreaker)
    {
        System.out.println("got doc");
        this.sd = sd;
        this.myNameFinder = mf;
        this.wordBreaker = wordBreaker;
        doc = document;
    }

    private static List<String> getMyDocsFromSomewhere()
    {
        //this should return an object that has all the info about the doc you want
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            String modelPath = "c:\\temp\\opennlpmodels\\";

            if (tm == null)
            {
                //user does normal namefinder instantiations...
                InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(modelPath + "en-token.zip"));
                // new SentenceDetectorME(new SentenceModel(new FileInputStream(new File(modelPath + "en-sent.zip"))));
                tm = new TokenizerModel(stream);
                // new TokenizerME(tm);
                locModel = new TokenNameFinderModel(new FileInputStream(new File(modelPath + "en-ner-location.bin")));
                //  new NameFinderME(locModel);
            }


            System.out.println("getting data");
            List<String> docs = getMyDocsFromSomewhere();
            System.out.println("\tdone getting data");
            // FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\apache\\modelbuilder\\sentences.txt");




            for (String docu : docs)
            {
                //you could also use the runnable here and launch in a diff thread
                new OpenNLPNER(docu,
                        new SentenceDetectorME(new SentenceModel(new FileInputStream(new File(modelPath + "en-sent.zip")))),
                        new NameFinderME(locModel), new TokenizerME(tm)).run();

            }

            System.out.println("done");


        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            process(doc);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void process(String document) throws Exception
    {

        //  System.out.println(document);
        //user instantiates the non static entitylinkerproperty object and constructs is with a pointer to the prop file they need to use
        String modelPath = "C:\\apache\\entitylinker\\";


        //input document
        myNameFinder.clearAdaptiveData();
        //user splits doc to sentences
        String[] sentences = sd.sentDetect(document);
        //get the sentence spans
        Span[] sentenceSpans = sd.sentPosDetect(document);
        Span[][] allnamesInDoc = new Span[sentenceSpans.length][];
        String[][] allTokensInDoc = new String[sentenceSpans.length][];

        for (int sentenceIndex = 0; sentenceIndex < sentences.length; sentenceIndex++)
        {
            String[] stringTokens = wordBreaker.tokenize(sentences[sentenceIndex]);
            Span[] tokenSpans = wordBreaker.tokenizePos(sentences[sentenceIndex]);
            Span[] spans = myNameFinder.find(stringTokens);
            allnamesInDoc[sentenceIndex] = spans;
            allTokensInDoc[sentenceIndex] = stringTokens;
        }

        //now access the data like this...
        for (int s = 0; s < sentenceSpans.length; s++)
        {
            Span[] namesInSentence = allnamesInDoc[s];
            String[] tokensInSentence = allTokensInDoc[s];
            String[] entities = Span.spansToStrings(namesInSentence, tokensInSentence);
            for (String entity : entities)
            {
                //start building up the XML here....
                System.out.println(entity + " Was in setnence " + s + " @ " + namesInSentence[s].toString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```